# Javascript closure behaves differently when bound to an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, closures

I am trying to use a closure to ensure that a function can only execute once.  Sounds simple, and it works like this:

```
function runOnce(fn)  // returns copy of fn which can only execute once
{
    var ran = false;

    return function() 
    {
        if (!ran)
        {
            fn();
            ran = true;
        }
    };
}
```

I have tested the function like so:

```
function lazyLoadGrid(event, ui)
{
    alert('hi');
}

var test1 = runOnce(lazyLoadGrid);
var test2 = runOnce(lazyLoadGrid);

test1();
test2();

test1();
test2();
```

And it works as expected - 'hi' gets alerted exactly twice.

But then I try to use runOnce(lazyLoadGrid) as the callback to a jQuery UI event:

```
$('.accordion').each(function() 
{ 
    $(this).accordion({ autoHeight: false, change: runOnce(lazyLoadGrid) });
});
```

And madness ensues.  What I expect is that each 'accordion' on the page will run lazyLoadGrid() exactly once, when that accordion is first opened.  Instead, the closure callbacks seem to behave as if they are all referencing the same copy of 'ran'.  lazyLoadGrid() runs the first time I open any accordion, and then never runs again for any other accordion.  Logging the pre-condition value of 'ran' shows that it's 'true' every time I click any accordion after the first one.

What is the explanation for this?  It may be worth noting I have an odd page, with nested accordions, and multiple jQuery UI tabs each containing accordions.  To make matters worse, when I switch tabs the closure actually does run on the first-opened accordion of any given tab.  Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce it here: http://jsfiddle.net/uphug/1/. Both IDs are logged only once and independently from each other.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `each` in your actual code?

Comment: Just want to say, this is an very well written question.

Comment: Can you post a link to a page -- ideally a jsFiddle -- that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Felix, I pasted the citations above direct from my actual code.  There is some context missing, like the fact that all the cited code (except the function definitions) runs inside $.ready().  I wasn't sure whether that could be relevant.

Comment: Perhaps a better approach is to see if the grid is present when the tab is opened. If not, load it. Otherwise, do nothing. That strategy seems more closely aligned with the intent of the function, rather than seeing if the function that loads the grid has run and assuming it's there if you think it has (or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem:

I believe the trouble you are having is because what you are thinking of as an "accordion" is actually a "panel".  The accordion consists of all the panels in a group.  It sounds like you want to run it once per panel, not once per accordion.  The following demo illustrates the concept by including two accordions on a page.  Notice that `lazyLoadGrid()` is run twice, once for each accordion:

http://jsfiddle.net/cTz4F/

### The solution:

Instead what you want to do is create a custom event and call that event on each panel.  Then you can take advantage of jQuery's built-in `.one()` method which causes that an event handler is called exactly once for each element:

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    change: function(e, ui) {
        ui.newHeader.trigger("activated");
    }
});
$('.accordion > h3').one("activated", lazyLoadGrid);
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/cTz4F/1/

Comment: Sadly, this is exactly what happened.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
function runOnce(fn) {
    return function(){
      fn();
      fn = function(){};
  }
}

// test 
var foo = function(){
    console.log('bar');
}
foo = runOnce(foo);
foo(); // bar
foo();
foo();
```

Comment: That works as well, but there is no reason that the OPs code won't work and @pimvdb shows in his demo that it actually *does* work. So presumably the problem is not with the code in the question, but somewhere else.

Comment: This won't work since overwriting a variable won't overwrite any property in any object.

Comment: @pimvdb - Wait.  What?  Why won't this work?  Replacing the implementation in your demo with this one works just the same:  http://jsfiddle.net/uphug/4/.

Comment: @gilly3: Woops. I thought `foo` was being overwritten. Never mind :)

Answer (score 0):

i think because the function expects the event parameter to be specified.
try this:

```
$('.accordion').each(function() { 
$(this).accordion({ autoHeight: false, change: runOnce(arguments[0],lazyLoadGrid) }); 
});
```

try using directly the function lazyLoadGrid or if you have to use the runOnce you have to specify the arguments[0] (which is the event) as a parameter in the function

-- edit --

sorry i forgot to put the event in the function

Comment: What's the difference to the OP's code? You never have to specify parameters for a function if you don't intend to use them.

Comment: for what he's doing you must specify the event because it won't be the same every time you call the function.

Comment: It still does not make much sense to me. In this case `arguments[0]` references the first argument passed to `each` which is the index of the element in the set. There is not event object here and why would `runOnce` need it anyway?

Comment: i used arguments[0] as the event of the calling function. when you set functions as onblur() or onchange(), at runtime, you have to specify the event in the function, like if you would code a button with the onchange(): the click of the button is the event for the function onchange.

Comment: Yes, but you don't *have to* specify it, only if you want to use it. And as I said, `arguments[0]` is not referring to the event object, because the event handler is not what is currently executed. The callback for `each` is executed, and `each` gets the index and element as arguments ([proof](http://jsfiddle.net/uphug/2/)). If any, you'd have to define `lazyLoadGrid` to accept an argument. Sorry, but your answer is just wrong.

Comment: if i understood what he's trying to do is that when one of the accordion change, it should execute a function. now he's doing this at runtime through JQuery. now for me he should just use one function passing the event for each accordion, and then from that function call the other function he needs. i would use event as parameter to pass to the function, but it doesn't work with all the broswers that's why i used to use arguments[0] that apparently solves the problem.

Comment: Well yes, in **event handlers** `arguments[0]` refers to an event object (jQuery already normalizes this for you btw, so you could just define the handler with an parameter). But the function that calls `$(this).accordion(...)` **is not an event handler** and therefore `arguments[0]` **does not refer to an event object**. It does not make any sense at all to use it here. That's my last comment for this as you don't seem to, or want to, understand me.

Comment: ok i understand what you are saying. So may i please ask you how would you solve this problem, then?
my answer is probably wrong, i misunderstood the request, but the concept i'm trying to explain you is right even because i have used it many times without problems. thanks btw for the explanation.

Comment: As I said as response to the other answer, there is nothing wrong with the OP's code. @primvdb demonstrated that it works correctly. It must be something else. There currently is no problem which needs to be solved.

Comment: oh ok, i had a look at the page on jsFiddle, the js console on google chrome says that there's an error "Error in event handler for 'undefined': undefined
chrome.Event.dispatch" but the console also actually writes "triggered" as the user wrote in his code.

Comment: I experimented plenty with the signatures of all the functions involved, and the behavior never changed.  I am thinking there is something going on with the nested jq-UI elements, or perhaps the fact that all the code I've cited runs inside a function to jQuery ready().  I neglected to mention that but considered it might have some effect.

Comment: @sacheie: How do you explain that it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/uphug/1/ ? There is probably something else wrong in your code.

Comment: @sacheie: why don't you try to write in jsFiddle your exact code? so maybe we can find out what the real problem is...

Comment: Being at home now, I have to make some changes to continue working.  However, I should be able to keep investigating shortly.  If I find any cause other than my own stupidity, I will try to reduce it to a simple demo on jsfiddle.  And I guess that's also what I'll have to do if I find no explanation at all ;)

Comment: many eyes are better than just two. and even if my answer wasn't helpfull i would try to help you as much as my knowlodge is. so don't rely on me loll